# REGISTRO C# SIN BASE DE DATOS Y PODER COMPARARLO CON UN LOGIN

Tags: c#, registro

queria hacer una consulta, estoy intentando realizar un registro pero sin base de datos todavia, es decir guardar los datos en algun array, o list para poder compararlo primero para iniciar sesion y despues para poder modificar ese perfil. Ya puedo hacerlo pero lo hago con una variable y claramente se guarda un usuario solo. Si pudieran ayudarme seria de mucha ayuda. dejo mi codigo del boton registrar e iniciar.

````
{
 
 
    string nombre = txtNombre.Text;
    string apellido = txtApellido.Text;
    string cedula = txtCedula.Text;
    string grupo = txtGrupo.Text;
    string contraseña = txtContraseña.Text;
    string confircontraseña= txtConfirmacion.Text;
    // si los datos no estan ingresados se marcara que faltan datos
    if (nombre == "NOMBRE" && apellido == "APELLIDO") {
        msgError("faltan datos");
            }
    else if (cedula == "CEDULA" && grupo == "GRUPO")
        {
        msgError("faltan datos");
    }
    else if (contraseña == "CONTRASEÑA" && confircontraseña == "CONFIRMAR CONTRASEÑA")
    {
        msgError("faltan datos");
    }
    if (confircontraseña == contraseña) { }
    else msgError("Las contraseñas no son iguales");
 
 
 
 
 
    //almacenamos los datos para usarlos en otro formulario
    Usuarios.usuarios = nombre + " " + apellido;
    Usuarios.contraseña = contraseña;
    Usuarios.cedula = cedula;
    Usuarios.grupo = grupo;  }
    }```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! un array de objetos? una lista de objetos? formas hay muchas.. y la documentacion seria enorme...

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que podrías que además te va a servir si en un futuro quieres pasarlo a base de datos sería crear una clase la cual añadirías ahí todos los datos del usuario. Una vez hecho esto creas una lista de objetos de tipo usuario por ejemplo, en la cual vas añadiendo en un FOREACH o en un For si sabes o recoges el número de veces que vas a añadir los datos. Algo tipo así:

```
List<Usuarios> Usuarios= new List<Usuarios>();  
foreach (var usuarios in Usuarios)
{
    usuarios.nombre.Add = nombre + " " + apellido;
    usuarios.contraseña.Add = contraseña;
    usuarios.cedula.Add = cedula;
    usuarios.grupo.Add = grupo; 
}
```

También se podría hacer con un datatable.

Comment: Por favor revisa el código de tu respuesta. Tienes una mezcla extraña entre un `foreach` y un `for`. ¿Por qué `Usuarios[i].propiedad` cuando debería ser `usuarios.propiedad`?

Comment: Fallo mío, iba a usar un for primero y usé el foreach primero. Gracias por el aviso!